# How can I specialize a type in a Frege QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, frege

I'd like to run the classical test for reversing a list. To this end, I have to specialize the list to a list of "Arbitrary" (sic!) types, e.g. [Int].

What works is

```
module ListCheck where

import Test.QuickCheck

myReverse :: [Int] -> [Int]
myReverse = reverse

reverse_of_reverse_is_original = property (\xs -> myReverse(myReverse xs) == xs)
```

or factoring out the invariant like

```
reverse_invariant :: [Int] -> Bool
reverse_invariant xs = reverse(reverse xs) == xs
reverse_of_reverse_is_original = property reverse_invariant
```

but I would rather want to not wrap the original function but use it directly. The usual Haskell trick of forcing a specialization through adding

```
... where types = xs :: [Int]
```

does not work here.

Is there a less verbose solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unfortunately the case that the

```
where types = xs :: [Int]
```

gets removed by the let expression simplification and canonicalization pass, which comes before type checking even.
This is, so to speak, a side effect of dependency analysis, where it is seen that `types` is totally useless.

You can write:

```
p_rev = property rev
    where rev (xs::[Int]) = (reverse . reverse) xs == xs
```

or even:

```
p_rev = forAll (arbitrary :: Gen [Int])
          (\xs -> (reverse . reverse) xs == xs)
```

Since one could write nonsense like

```
where types = 1:true:"foo" + Just []
```

and it would still get removed, it would arguably be better to remove unused lets only after typechecking.

Comment: I've not tried this, but could you just stick a type signature on `reverse` itself? `property (\xs -> (reverse::[Int]->[Int]) (reverse xs) == xs)`

Comment: @dfeuer Correct, it doesn't matter where you stick the type signature, as long as it is not in an unused let/where definition and the type of `xs` can be derived from it.